# How to get the facebook friends email address using api?

Tags: facebook

**I get current user email Address** I need to get the facebook friends email

Comment: Via graph api or fql ? Using what programming language?

Comment: Why would you vote to close this question as a duplicate of a closed question. @_@

Answer (score 4):

Read the documentation here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/

It is mentioned clearly that you cannot obtain it, quoting from documentation

> (Note: There is no way for apps to obtain email addresses for a user's friends.)